# Single Sign On from MVC 4 to .Net Core application

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-core, asp.net-identity

We are trying to implement single sign on, across multiple domains from MVC 4 application to .Net Core application.
MVC 4 to MVC 4 it's working fine with MachinKey, but not with .Net core.
How can we implement SSO to share the same authentication with all other application in MVC4 and .Net core application.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Identity Server can do this. Identity Server version 4 will be supported and free for as long as .NET Core 3.1 is supported. After that, you'll need Duende Identity Server, which is the next version, available on a commercial licence.
You can also do it with OpenID Connect (AKA OpenIddict) which is free for the foreseeable future, but that will probably need you to write a bit more code.

I have used both.

Both of them are agnostic to the type of client applications, so your clients can be MVC4, .NET Core, Xamarin, React, anything at all. Both of them have good templates that you can download and get started quite quickly with a simple scenario.

Unfortunately, in my experience, making meaningful extensions or changes to the templates (such as what you're proposing) was difficult and required in-depth knowledge of internet security concepts, studying the documentation and source code of whichever library that you choose.

I have tried really hard to learn but I still find it difficult, so I wish you good luck!

Here are the sample projects for IdentityServer4:

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Templates

And here is the documentation on how to get started:
http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/

Here are the sample projects for Open Id Connect:
https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples

And here is the documentation:
https://openid.net/connect/

Comment: Could you please share sample code of this?

Comment: Yup! I've added links to code samples and docs for both frameworks to my answer.